# Loading images from Storage to Cloud Functions in Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm using a python Cloud Function that accesses files in Cloud Storage. I am using `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` to load the files. However this appears to be relatively slow considering the cloud function and the storage are hosted in the same place. Is there are faster way to do this? Perhaps in the Firebase Admin SDK?

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK just wraps the existing Cloud SDK for each platform.

Comment: Define slow. How large are the objects and how long does it take? To increase compute power and network speed, increase the memory allocated to your function.